# redirect to different route when root url changes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs

I am developing an anuglar + nodejs app and run into this problem. I want to set up the following url mapping:

1. localhost:3000/ => node server serves index.html on server side and then anuglar serve partial view index.html on client side (there are two index.html one on server-side one client-side )
   localhost:3000/signup => angular routeProvider serves partial view signup.html into index.html (ajax so no reload)
2. localhost:3000/customerLoggedin =>node server serves customerLoggedin.html and maybe angular serves some other partials (page reload)
   localhost:3000/customerLoggedin/order-form => angular routeProvider serves partial view order.html (ajax)

And I have the following code:

angular side:

system.js:

```
angular.module('myApp.system').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
            // For unmatched routes:
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            // states for my app
            $stateProvider.state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'public/system/views/partials/index.html' // there are two index.html one on the server side (which is the layout) and one served by angular
                }).state('signup',{
                url:'/signup',
                    templateUrl:'public/system/views/partials/signup.html'
                }).state('payment',{
                    url:'/payment',
                    templateUrl:'public/system/views/partials/payment.html',
                    controller:'paymentCtrl'
                }).state('order',{
                    url:'/order-form',
                    templateUrl:'public/system/views/partials/order.html',
                    controller:'orderCtrl'
                });
        }
    ])
```

customerLoggedin.html:

```
   ...
   <a href='/order-form'><span>New Order</span></a>
   ...
   <section data-ui-view ng-view class='view-animate'/>
   ...
```

routes on the node server:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/customerLoggedIn',function(req,res){
        res.render('customerLoggedIn');
        });

        app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.render('index');
        });

};
```

right now the problem is when I hit on the "new order" link in customerLoggedin.html angular gives me client-sdie index.html which should only show up in localhost:3000/index.html . I want  angular to serve the partial view order.html into the ngview in customerLoggedin.html

How to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) directive to trigger the state change instead of pointing to the url

```
<a ui-sref='order'>New Order</a>
```

Comment: That may work but how do you solve the problem when the browser first load http://localhost:3000/customerLoggedIn/ angular thinks it is "/" and loads index.html ?

Comment: if localhost:3000/customerLoggedIn is a different rendered html it will essentially be a different angular application with a different set of states. Your alternative is to have /customerLoggedIn as another route in your main angular app served from index.html